# Corrective Actions Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

Good afternoon all,

I am trying to set up a corrective and/or preventative actions (CAPA) workflow using SharePoint Lists. In our system we have paper based forms which collect information on how the CAPA was identified (e.g. Internal Audit) a description of the issue, who it was assigned to and so on. We then have a section on actions undertaken, and finally an outcome section which highlights what was done, likelihood of recurrence et al.

At the end of the project, the director needs to sign off on the corrective action. I am wondering if there is a way I can automate this process within SharePoint Lists, and Flow et al.

My thought was to have a list and assign an entry to a specific person, but I am not sure how I can get them to fill out more information, and to then trigger approval by the managing director (approval is not that it does not exist, but rather it can be closed).

Id be keen to find out how other people handle their CAPA workflow in sharepoint, and any automation they have been able to bring into it to make it easier?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need more than one workflow/flow to cover the corrective and preventative action (CAPA) action.

For example, configure workflows/flows to automate actions such as creating non-conformances and initiating CAPA requests automatically. Or use workflows/flows to replace traditional paper-based process.

In addition, Microsoft flow is more convenient and efficient for SharePoint Online than SharePoint Designer workflow.

Here are a few posts with related consideration/solution for your reference.

[Regulatory Compliance with SharePoint.](http://blog.scicomputing.com/regulatory-compliance-with-sharepoint/)

[Using Microsoft SharePoint as the ISO Quality Management System to Meet your ISO CAPA Standards.](https://www.abelsolutions.com/using-microsoft-sharepoint-as-the-iso-quality-management-system-to-meet-your-iso-capa-standards/)